# Best way to use Ektron FormBlockControl with Captcha?

Tags: ektron

I am working with ektron 9.Suppose i have some html forms in ektron workarea.
I need to validate the form in ektron page builder page with captcha.
Is there any way to do it with Ekron form control, or there any way to achieve the same in ektron?

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample on the Ektron Customer Portal for this.
https://portal.ektron.com/KB/10246/

example below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Ektron.Cms.Framework.UI.Controls" Namespace="Ektron.Cms.Framework.UI.Controls" TagPrefix="cms" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cms" Namespace="Ektron.Cms.Controls" Assembly="Ektron.Cms.Controls" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                captcha1.Visible = false;
            }
        }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%-- You will need to change the DefaultFormID --%>
    <ektron:FormControl id="FormBlock1" runat="server" DefaultFormID="414" AddValidation="True" DynamicParameter="ekfrm"></ektron:FormControl> 
     <cms:Captcha ID="captcha1" runat="server" Visible="true"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The form block control reads the forms' values very early in the page life cycle. The only way to prevent the form block control from reading the values is to throw an exception in the pre-init. The response.Redirect throws a thread abort exception. You can redirect to the same page. In that case the user loses all their inputs. If you combine that with some client side validation, then the user should only fail on the server side if they are a hacker who defeated the client side validation.